# SSIS Derived Column - Parse Text between break returns

Tags: ssis

I have a text field from a SQL Server Source. It is a phone number field that typically has this format:

```
Home: 555-555-1212
Work: 555-555-1212
Cell: 555-555-1212
Emergency: 555-555-1212
```

I'm trying to split among fields so that only 555-555-1212 is displayed

I am then taking this field and converting to a string. There are literally break returns (\r\n) between the labels here. The goal here is to have this data split among multiple fields (home,work,cell,emergency,etc.) I was researching how to split text among fields and I made some progress. In the case of home numbers, I used this logic:

```
SUBSTRING(Phone_converted,FINDSTRING(Phone_converted,"Home:",1) + 5,FINDSTRING(Phone_converted,"\n",1) - FINDSTRING(Phone_converted,"Home:",1) - 5)
```

This works great as it parses up to the text return and I get 555-555-1212.

Now I experience an issue when searching for a text between break returns. I tried the same logic for Work numbers:

```
 SUBSTRING(Phone_converted,FINDSTRING(Phone_converted,"Work:",1) + 5,FINDSTRING(Phone_converted,"\n",1) - FINDSTRING(Phone_converted,"Work:",1) - 5)
```

But that won't work and results in writing to my error redirection file. I then tried to insert a break return to find the text at the beginning

```
SUBSTRING(Phone_converted,FINDSTRING(Phone_converted,"\nWork:",1) + 5,FINDSTRING(Phone_converted,"\n",1) - FINDSTRING(Phone_converted,"\nWork:",1) - 5)
```

No luck there either. Any ideas on how I can address this. Also, I would appreciate an idea of how I can handle the emergency title at the end. There won't be a break return in that situation, but I still want to parse the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I look at your data and I see

Home:|555-555-1212|Work:|555-555-1212|Cell:|555-555-1212|Emergency:|555-555-1212

I'm using the pipe character, |, as a placeholder for where I would segment that string, which is basically wherever you have whitespace (space, tab, newline, etc).

There are two approaches to this. I'll start with the easy one.

## Script Component

[String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend here. Look at what it did with that source data

I added a new Script Component, acting as a Transformation and created 4 output columns, all string of length 12 codepage 1252: Home, Work, Cell, and Emergency. I populate them like so

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    string[] split = Row.PhoneData.Split();

    Row.Home = split[1];
    Row.Work = split[4];
    Row.Cell = split[7];
    Row.Emergency = split[10];
}
```

## Derived Column

I'm not going to build out a full blown implementation of this. The above is much to simple but I run into situations where ETL devs say they aren't allowed to use Script tasks/components and that's usually because people reached for them first instead of last.

The approach here is to have lots of Derived Columns Components on your Data Flow. It won't hurt performance and in fact can make it easier. It *definitely* will make your debugging easier as you'll have lots of it to do.

### DER Find Colons

This would add 4 columns into the dataflow - HomeColonPosition, WorkColonPosition etc. You've already started down this path but just build it out into the actual data flow as you'll need to reference these positions and again, it's easier to fix the calculation that populates a column versus a calculation that's wrong and used everywhere. You're likely to find that 4 derived columns are useful here as you'd want to use the previous colon's position as the starting point for the third argument to `FINDSTRING`

Thus, instead of Work being

```
FINDSTRING(PhoneData, ":", FINDSTRING(PhoneData, ":" 1) + 1)
```

it would just be

```
FINDSTRING(PhoneData, ":", HomeColonPosition + 1)
```

Just knowing the position of the 4 colons in that string, I can figure out where the phone numbers are (maybe). The position of the colon + 2 (colon and the space) is the starting point and then go out 12 characters.

Where this approach gets ugly, much as it did with the script approach is when that data isn't consistent.

Comment: Unfortunately I found out the data was quite inconsistent since it was a free text field. I did end up creating multiple conditional splits and derived columns to accomplish what I needed.